# How to display sub response when search Tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I can show skill(List)(only vName) as rows and CategorySkill show as section in tableview.

but the issue is I want to filter only VName when search using searchcontroller? and I don't know what to write logic in below method

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) { }
```

my response data is

```
Results<CategorySkill> <0x7fe174473280> (
        [0] CategorySkill {
            id = 01;
            name = Name1;
            skill = List<Skill> <0x600001f84aa0> (

                [0] Skill {
                    skilid = 01;
                    skillCat = 01;
                    vName = Name2 ;
                },
                [1] Skill {
                    skilid = 01;
                    skillCat = 01;
                    vName = Name2 ;
                }
            );
        },
        [1] CategorySkill {
                id = 01;
                name = Name1;
                skill = List<Skill> <0x600001f84a00> (
                [0] Skill {
                    skilid = 01;
                    skillCat = 01;
                    vName = Name2 ;
                },
                [1] Skill {
                    skilid = 01;
                    skillCat = 01;
                    vName = Name2 ;
                }
            );
        },
        [2] CategorySkill {
                id = 01;
                name = Name1;
            skill = List<Skill> <0x600001f84dc0> (
                [0] Skill {
                    skilid = 01;
                    skillCat = 01;
                    vName = Name2 ;
                },
                [1] Skill {
                    skilid = 01;
                    skillCat = 01;
                    vName = Name2 ;
                }
            );
        }
        
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer here where I have mentioned how you can search in a nested array and show in search result.'

[how to filter section wise row in tableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67748348/how-to-filter-section-wise-row-in-tableview)